# Django Models and Admin interface question

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am preparing a Examination website for my students. Simple website, with use of Django's admin interface to create the Question paper.

I have following models:

```
class Paper(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=2000, unique=False)
    short_desc = models.TextField(unique=False)

class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(unique=False)
    order = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    paper = models.ForeignKey(Paper, unique=False)
```

While adding questions to the paper, I want that I should be able to add the question from the Paper's admin interface itself, by clicking a "+" sign or some kind of "add more questions" etc.

In my current setup, I have to first create the paper and then go into Question interface and add them one by one (and heaven's forbid) if I lose their `order` number.

Remember, each Question belongs to a Paper and it is not a ManyToMany thing here.

Do I have to modify the admin in any way or am I doing it wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *The admin interface has the ability to
>   edit models on the same page as a
>   parent model. These are called
>   inlines. See [InlineModelAdmin](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)*

Create a `QuestionInline`:

```
class QuestionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Question
```

and in `PaperAdmin` add:

```
class PaperAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    inlines = [
        QuestionInline,
    ]
```

Comment: Did exactly what you asked me to but the Paper still does not show the Question inline. I deleted my database and re-sync(ed) everything but still no good. Am I missing something?

Comment: None. runserver worked and I logged into admin section but it looked like same old normal Paper admin view.

Answer (score 1):

InlineModelAdmin is what you're after. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects for the details